# Copy same root directory with files to multiple wildcard directories including files

Tags: xcopy

I am trying to copy one folder and its contents to multiple user directories which vary depending on the username. The directory under each user will remain constant.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

xcopy "C:\OF" "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming" /O /X /E /H /K /S

I am trying to use a wildcard because the username is different, but xcopy apparently cannot use wildcards any longer?

The directory of "C:\OF" will have files and other nested directories and I want to place those under the "Roaming" directory.

Thank you for any help and explanation of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's not that xcopy can't use wildcards, it just can't use them that way I believe.

Comment: I found a similar issue/post, but I am not getting the syntax right:

http://superuser.com/questions/641894/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-a-destination-with-a-wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR  /d %%I IN (C:\Users\*) DO (

XCOPY "C:\OF" "%%I\AppData\Roaming"/O /X /E /H /K /S
)
```

That should do want you want.  I didn't validate your XCOPY switches because I stopped using XCOPY years ago in favor of ROBOCOPY.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I ran this code and saw that 86 files were copied. However, nothing was actually copied to any folder.

I would gladly use robocopy as well but xcopy was the first thing that came to mind :)

Comment: Thanks. I got this to work, but it has prompts asking if I want to overwrite Yes/No/All. Is there a way to script it to answer ? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Check XCOPY/? but I think /Y should turn off all prompts and answer them affirmatively.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
@echo off
    for /d %%x in (C:\Users\*) do xcopy "C:\OF" "%%x\AppData\Roaming\OF\*" /d /e
pause
EXIT
```